# How Do I Find SSL Certificate Full Path And Use in a StoredProcedure to call an API

Tags: sql-server, ssl, asp.net-core, certificate, java-stored-procedures

How do I find the ssl certificate path? That one installed by VisualStudio, to be more expecific when we use .NET Core and run "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" at the console...

Could you guys help me pls?

Everything I've tried drop me in the certificate name only. I could not see the path to set on that pattern 'LOCAL_MACHINE\My\'Certificate Name'.

I want to pass it ike a parameter on the SQL code below:

EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod
           @Object,
           'setOption',
           NULL,
           3,
           'LOCAL_MACHINE\My\'Certificate Name';

Just because I'm trying to call a API using SQL Server and I need to use that SSL certificate to run my tests.

Could you guys help me pls?

The return message I've got untill now says that it's not a valid certificate but I think it's bacause I'm not finding the full path.

I don't know if I made this clear... Just summarazing... I need to do this by sql and I need to know how to use SSL certificate path as a parameter.

There follows the code I'm using:

```
begin
declare @test as int;
declare @Object as int;
declare @hResult as nvarchar(256)
declare @Response as nvarchar(256)

exec @test = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object out;
select @test, @Object;

EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod
           @Object,
           'setOption',
           NULL,
           3,
           'LOCAL_MACHINE\My\'Certificate Name';

exec @test = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', null, 'get',
 'https://localhost:44351/api/v1/account/3215', 'false'

select @test
exec @test = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
IF @test <> 0 
BEGIN 
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object 
RETURN 
END
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @Response OUTPUT;
end

print @Response
```

Comment: What are you trying to achive by the sql code? What do you mean by `use that SSL certificate to run my testes.`? If you need to sign a sp by certificate, you need to create the certiciate by sql and refer [Tutorial: Signing Stored Procedures with a Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I'm trying to call a web API by sql due the context and the need of the sprint that was assigned  to me, it's like an auditing on data bases that people want to receive by Papertrail warning in real time. The API that I am trying to call is responsible to genrate a log and export to Papertrail which is responsible to send alerts by e-mail and Slack to other peopple. The only way I founded to dosuch thing was make sql achieve the API. But the API uses a SSL that I got to use on the sp. I'm testing in localhost using that certificate generated by Visual Studio just to development environment.

Comment: I updated the question with more information. Tks!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into to exactly the same issue. Everything points to the certificate created by VS2022 being valid and trusted, but I am getting the "Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid. " error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using the same VS-generated cert.  I could find the cert called "localhost" in the certmgr ("Personal"->"Certificates"->localhost), installed when I began the project.  I added this line:

```
EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @Object,'setOption',NULL,3,'LOCAL_MACHINE\My\localhost';
```

and it worked.
However, i found I could change the line to anything and it still worked, ie:

```
EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @Object,'setOption',NULL,3,'LOCAL_MACHINE\My\bogusfake';
```

So I cannot promise that will work for you, nor explain how/why, but I am able to proceed with the project of posting from a stored procedure to a local api.  The only difference I see between my code and yours is I didn't surround the cert name in quotes.